# PyTorch: what is the exact shape of x when call model(x)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm confused about the shapes of `X` and `pred` when reading the PyTorch tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html

In the following code (training part), it's obvious that the shape of `X` is `(64,1,28,28)`, and the shape of `pred` is `(64, 10)`. 64 is the batch size.

```
model.train()
for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
    X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

    # Compute prediction error
    pred = model(X)
```

But in the predicting part below, the shape of `X` is (1,28,28) without `batch_size`, but `pred` is still (1, 10) with `batch_size`. I thought `X` and `pred` should both with `batch_size` or both without `batch_size`. Why?

```
model.eval()
x, y = test_data[0][0], test_data[0][1]
with torch.no_grad():
    x = x.to(device)
    pred = model(x)
    predicted, actual = classes[pred[0].argmax(0)], classes[y]
    print(f'Predicted: "{predicted}", Actual: "{actual}"')
```